# Scanner.nextDouble : txt file correctly loaded but "InputMismatchException" occurs

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, uncaught-exception

I've a text (file.txt) file . This file is loaded inside a scanner.

In the files there are various lines and in each line there are two doubles and one integer values divided by spaces.

Like this:

```
1.0 1.2 2
0.9 1.0 10
50.4 9.2 20
```

I need to fulfill three arrays.

Each array corresponds to a **column**. Something like:

```
double[] x = {1.0,0.9,50.4}
double[] y = {1.2,1.0,9.2}
double[] z = {2,10,20}
```

I tried to to this using this code:

```
double x[]= new double [3];
double y[]= new double [3];
double z[]= new double [3];

File f = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(file.txt).toURI());
Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

for (int i=0;j<3;i++){
  x[i] = sc.nextDouble();
  y[i] = sc.nextDouble();
  z[i] = sc.nextDouble();
}
```

but when the first nextDouble() is executed an "uncaught" (java.util.InputMismatchException) exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for any hint.

Comment: Print `sc.next()` and see what the scanner tries to parse as a double.

Comment: I tried. And indeed in 4 iterations it takes the three numbers of the first line and the first number of the fourth line so exactly as it should be but when I try the same with nextDouble() it fails in the FIRST iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `sc.next()` works for you, you need to parse your output as it is of the type `String` and hence a `InputMismatchException`.

try:

```
for (int i=0;j<3;i++) {
  String s;
  s = sc.next();
  x[i] = Double.parseDouble(s);
  s = sc.next();
  y[i] = Double.parseDouble(s);
  s = sc.next();
  z[i] = Double.parseDouble(s);
}
```

Comment: But next() returns only ONE (of the three) doubles of one line. And it says the split (or split) methods doesn't exist

Comment: well if it returns one of the three doubles at a time,then you don't have to split them,simply parse them and use them.

Comment: ok I have some problem with indexes but now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Is it something related to `Locale` you are parsing `doubles` ?

Citation from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

> An instance of this class is capable of scanning numbers in the standard formats as well as in the formats of the scanner's locale. A scanner's initial locale is the value returned by the `Locale.getDefault()` method; it may be changed via the `useLocale(java.util.Locale)` method.

So, for example, this could help:

```
scanner.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the program, try a comma instead of a dot:

```
1,0 1,2 2

0,9 1,0 10

50,4 9,2 20
```